# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag: definitions

Tags: web-services, jboss6.x

I m trying to call web service using apache axix but i get below exception. Please help me. I m using below tech:
JBoss - 6.0
Seam - 2.1.2
EJB3, JSF.

The web service works fine in JBoss-4.2.3 but when i try to run in JBoss-6.0 it gives me an error.

```
11:48:13,759 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag:  definitions
11:48:13,760 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.message.EnvelopeBuilder.startElement(EnvelopeBuilder.java:71)
11:48:13,760 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1048)
11:48:13,760 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,760 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,761 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,761 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,761 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,761 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,762 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,762 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,762 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,762 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,763 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
11:48:13,763 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
11:48:13,763 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
11:48:13,763 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 104 more
```

Answer (score 5):

This almost surely means you have set the service endpoint using the WSDL location rather than the resource endpoint location.

Answer (score 4):

**Wrong format of the endpoint**

Ex: http://localhost:8080/YourService/

Ex: http://localhost:8080/YourService?wsdl

**Correct endpoint format to set the constructor**

Ex: http://localhost:8080/YourService

Comment: For me it was `https://domain/api/wsdl?ws=1` instead of just `https://domain/api/wsdl`. Good hint anyway!